# This brittle OData to SQL Server C# code isn't sustainable over time

Tags: c#, api, http, wcf, ssis

The intent of this code is to access a third party OData API to capture only the relevant data to an existing in-house set of MSSQL server tables. Ignore the exception handling for now--the errors will get written to a log. I'm not there yet.

I have no ego attached to this code. If any of you have better practical approaches to managing 3rd party OData/API extracts, please suggest them. I have only one caveat, that is that the C# snippets you see here will actually live in an SSIS script component--meaning that any 3rd party tools, libraries, etc. will not be available through NuGet.

Here's the core access class snippet:

```
           string fodepartmentEntitiesName = "FODepartment";
           string odataFODepartmentQueryParameters = "$orderby=externalCode desc&$top=2";
           string requestFODepartmentUri = String.Format("{0}?{1}", fodepartmentEntitiesName, odataFODepartmentQueryParameters);
           HttpResponseMessage responseFODepartment = client.GetAsync(requestFODepartmentUri).Result;

           string contentFODepartmentAsString = responseFODepartment.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

           XmlDocument xmfod = new XmlDocument();
           xmfod.LoadXml(contentFODepartmentAsString);

           // write whole object to dictionary
           odataSF.AddToDictionary(fodepartmentEntitiesName, xmfod);
```

This is later in the code:

```
           // read back object from dictionary
           XmlDocument xdocfod = new XmlDocument();
           xdocfod = odataSF.ReadFromDictionaryByKey(fodepartmentEntitiesName);
```

This takes the raw xml captured in the Dictionary through a cleansing process -- which includes shaving off the namespaces to a bare-bones xml doc to pass off to sql server. The original xml is kept separately in an archive table later in the code.

```
           string docfodepartments = extractSFobjects.GetFODepartmentData(xdocfod);
           XmlDocument xmlfodepartments = new XmlDocument();

           // This is our now cleansed/abbreviated xml for mssql consumption
           xmlfodepartments.LoadXml(docfodepartments);
```

Snippet from GetDODepartmentData-- This is very brittle, but sadly it is all I could come up with today.

```
    public string GetFODepartmentData(XmlDocument xdoc)
    {
        string docfodepartments = "";

        try
        {
            XmlNodeReader nodeReader = new XmlNodeReader(xdoc);
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.None;

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            string endtag = "</FODepartments>";
            string begtag = "<FODepartments>";

            // used for restating raw Xml to abbreviated, easy to pass on to mssql cleansed version
            XmlDocument xmlfodepartments = new XmlDocument();


            // obtain the raw xml from success factors 
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(nodeReader, settings);
            XElement data = XElement.Load(reader);
            XmlNameTable table = reader.NameTable;
            XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(table);
            manager.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
            manager.AddNamespace("m", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata");
            manager.AddNamespace("d", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices");
            manager.AddNamespace("base", "https://api20.ourthirdparty.com:443/odata/v2/");
            foreach (XElement entries in data.XPathSelectElements("./ns:entry", manager))
            {
                foreach (var contents in (from entry in entries.Elements() where entry.Name.LocalName.Contains("content") select entry))
                {
                    foreach (var properties in (from content in contents.Elements() where content.Name.LocalName.Contains("properties") select content))
                    {

                        foreach (var property in (from property in properties.Elements()
                                                  where property.Name.LocalName.Contains("startDate")
                                                         || property.Name.LocalName.Contains("externalCode")
                                                         || property.Name.LocalName.Contains("headOfUnit")
                                                         || property.Name.LocalName.Contains("status")
                                                         || property.Name.LocalName.Contains("parent")
                                                         || property.Name.LocalName.Contains("location")
                                                         || property.Name.LocalName.Contains("endDate")
                                                         || property.Name.LocalName.Contains("lastModifiedDateTime")
                                                         || property.Name.LocalName.Contains("lastModifiedOn")
                                                         || property.Name.LocalName.Contains("createdOn")
                                                         || property.Name.LocalName.Contains("createdBy")
                                                         || property.Name.LocalName.Contains("name")
                                                         || property.Name.LocalName.Contains("createdDateTime")
                                                         || property.Name.LocalName.Contains("lastModifiedBy")


                                                  select property)

                                 )

                            // get all the instances the positions w/tags and values
                            sb.Append(string.Format("<{0}>{1}</{0}>", property.Name.LocalName, property.Value, property.Name.LocalName));

                        // add the root tag sets
                        docfodepartments = begtag + sb.ToString() + endtag;

                    }

                }

            }

                // Correct missing tags with regex
            // Note: This code is a pure hack and needs to be revisited.
            Regex tag1 = new Regex(@"<startDate>");
            Regex tag2 = new Regex(@"</lastModifiedBy>");
            docfodepartments = tag1.Replace(docfodepartments, "<FODepartment><startDate>");
            docfodepartments = tag2.Replace(docfodepartments, "</lastModifiedBy></FODepartment>");
            // Correct ampersand xml conversion failures
            // Note: The ampersand was an ill-placed value from a test case, but still made it to the raw xml--there's nothing to prevent it.

            docfodepartments = docfodepartments.Replace("&", "and");  // return scrubbed string for xdoc conversion

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Console.WriteLine("Failed to collect Position data: " + ex.Message + " docpositons set to: " + docpositions);
            // will return a stub doc back.
            docfodepartments = bodydoc + " FODepartments " + enddoc;
        }

        return docfodepartments;
    }

    #endregion
```

Then finally the xdoc gets passed off to an existing sql server stored proc.

```
    #region invoke load FODepartment
    public void LoadOurThirdPartyFODepartmentData(XmlDocument xmlfodepartments)
    {
        try
        {
            dao.InsertFODepartmentRows(xmlfodepartments, stagingdb);
        }
        catch (Exception dx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Data Access Layer Exception: " + dx.Message + "\n");
        }

    }
    #endregion
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Focusing on `GetFODepartmentData()` method**

This method is really hard to read, especially the inner most loop, where you didn't add braces `{}`.

After extracting the creation of the XmlNamespaceManager object to a separate method

```
private XmlNamespaceManager GetXmlNamespaceManager(XmlNameTable table)
{
    XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(table);
    manager.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
    manager.AddNamespace("m", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata");
    manager.AddNamespace("d", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices");
    manager.AddNamespace("base", "https://api20.ourthirdparty.com:443/odata/v2/");
    return manager;
}
```

and extracting the `Contains` condition beast to a separate method

```
private bool IsNeededProperty(String localName)
{
    return localName.Contains("startDate")
        || localName.Contains("externalCode")
        || localName.Contains("headOfUnit")
        || localName.Contains("status")
        || localName.Contains("parent")
        || localName.Contains("location")
        || localName.Contains("endDate")
        || localName.Contains("lastModifiedDateTime")
        || localName.Contains("lastModifiedOn")
        || localName.Contains("createdOn")
        || localName.Contains("createdBy")
        || localName.Contains("name")
        || localName.Contains("createdDateTime")
        || localName.Contains("lastModifiedBy");
}
```

Which could be done better, like adding a `IList<String>` containing these strings and then using a loop which returns true at the moment where `localName.Contains(element)` would be true.

Your former method could be reduced to

```
public string GetFODepartmentData(XmlDocument xdoc)
{
    string docfodepartments = String.Empty;

    try
    {
        XmlNodeReader nodeReader = new XmlNodeReader(xdoc);
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.None;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        string endtag = "</FODepartments>";
        string begtag = "<FODepartments>";

        // obtain the raw xml from success factors 
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(nodeReader, settings);
        XElement data = XElement.Load(reader);
        XmlNameTable table = reader.NameTable;
        XmlNamespaceManager manager = GetXmlNamespaceManager(table);

        XElement entry = data.XPathSelectElements("./ns:entry", manager).Last();
        XElement contents = entry.Elements().Last(el => el.Name.LocalName.Contains("content"));
        XElement properties = contents.Elements().Last(el => el.Name.LocalName.Contains("properties"));

        foreach (var property in (from property in properties.Elements()
                                    where IsNeededProperty(property.Name.LocalName)
                                    select property)
                    )
        {
            // get all the instances the positions w/tags and values
            sb.Append(string.Format("<{0}>{1}</{0}>", property.Name.LocalName, property.Value, property.Name.LocalName));
        }

        // add the root tag sets
        docfodepartments = begtag + sb.ToString() + endtag;


        // Correct missing tags with regex
        // Note: This code is a pure hack and needs to be revisited.
        Regex tag1 = new Regex(@"<startDate>");
        Regex tag2 = new Regex(@"</lastModifiedBy>");
        docfodepartments = tag1.Replace(docfodepartments, "<FODepartment><startDate>");
        docfodepartments = tag2.Replace(docfodepartments, "</lastModifiedBy></FODepartment>");
        // Correct ampersand xml conversion failures
        // Note: The ampersand was an ill-placed value from a test case, but still made it to the raw xml--there's nothing to prevent it.

        docfodepartments = docfodepartments.Replace("&", "and");  // return scrubbed string for xdoc conversion

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Console.WriteLine("Failed to collect Position data: " + ex.Message + " docpositons set to: " + docpositions);
        // will return a stub doc back.
        docfodepartments = bodydoc + " FODepartments " + enddoc;
    }

    return docfodepartments;
}
```

Consider to use `String.Empty` over `""` as it is cleaner to read.

As the XmlReader implements `IDisposable` it should be enclosed inside a [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement.

The replacements using regex and string, should be extracted to a separate method also.

Comment: thanks so much for weeding through this. I will implement your suggestions--right now there are 16+ of these objects similar to FODepartment.

Comment: "using a loop which returns true at the moment where `localName.Contains(element)` would be true" Or you can use LINQ: `return elementNames.Any(name => localName.Contains(name));`.